# Ubuntu One sync seems frozen?

Tags: ubuntu-one

***Using Ubuntu 11.04***

I started Ubuntu One today, and put 14 files in the sync folder.
The total size of the 14 files is 295 MB.

After 11 hours, and since about 5 hours ago, the command

```
  u1sdtool --current
```

shows the same thing

```
Current uploads:
  path: /home/ubuntuone/20110524/home-dev-all-20110524.tar.gz
    deflated size: 45355790
    bytes written: 45355790
  path: /home/ubuntuone/20110524/home-misc-20110524.tar.gz
    deflated size: 68366485
    bytes written: 68366485
  path: /home/ubuntuone/20110524/home-windoze-20110524.tar.gz
    deflated size: 42369328
    bytes written: 42369328
  path: /home/ubuntuone/20110524/home-Documents-20110524.tar.gz
    deflated size: 86213754
    bytes written: 86213754
Current downloads: 0
```

and the state also is the same:

```
$ u1sdtool -s
State: QUEUE_MANAGER
    connection: With User With Network
    description: processing the commands pool
    is_connected: True
    is_error: False
    is_online: True
    queues: WORKING
```

The U1 page tells me that my files are 62 MB (~5%).

Is it supposed to be that long?
Is there a problem?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, been trying for several days with no progress on my sync!

Comment: Never mind. Installed *dropbox* using the installer for Ubuntu. Install took 1 mn. Total sync took 20 mn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a complete numpty I clicked all the green ubuntu one blocks for reinstallation in synaptic manager - all seems to work now!

Answer (score 1):

maybe this page is worth a look: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status#Files
today i had the same problem and there was the explanation: "2011-10-28 Windows and Ubuntu 11.10 users may experience issues with not all files syncing due to a bug we're currently working on fixing."

greetings